# Jquery slider with progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, progress-bar

I have setup and jsfiddler: 
http://jsfiddle.net/semantic/6SaJK/2/

I need the slide to be on auto rotate and the progress-bar for each slide need to fill from 0 to 50px width. I have the rest implemented, but struggling with the rest of logic to be implemented. please note, that I want to use the existing code. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6SaJK/28/

Comment: And you probably will need to call the `run()` function from your click handlers

Comment: thank you @Ulan, this is great, it nearly there, but I want to animate the specific index of the progress-bar <li></li> element with each slide change. not the full progress bar. if that's is done, I am happy with it. thank you for your time.

Comment: Ok, then take a look at this, hopefully this is what you are intending to do: http://jsfiddle.net/6SaJK/46/

Comment: Thanks Ulan, this is all I needed, the rest I will handle it to pause it when mouse over on the item. and when click on the item it should coordinate with each index element.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment because I lack reputation on stackoverflow so my thought goes here.

OP, remember that when you'll be working on pause for slider and your progress bar you can get slight differences in timings. The bug-proof answer for every slider that needs to have animated progress bar is firing the "next" event of your slider when the progress bar finishes he's job.

With jQuery Cycle 2 you can achieve it with something like this:

```
function main_slider() {

    if ( $("#slider").length ) {

    var $time = 7000;
    var $speed = 500;
    var $slide_width = $("#slider").width()

    $("#slider .cycle").on("cycle-initialized", function(event, opts) {
      var $slider = $("#slider");
      var $progress = $("#slider .progress");
      var $animator = $("#slider .progress .animator");
      var propWidth = $animator.width() / $progress.width() * 100;

      $animator.animate({
        width: "100%"
      }, $time * (100 - propWidth) / 100, function(){
        $("#slider .cycle").cycle("next");
      });

    });    

    $("#slider .cycle").cycle({
      fx: "scrollHorz",
      timeout: 0,
      speed: $speed,
      slides: "li",
      next: "#slider nav .next",
      prev: "#slider nav .prev",
      pauseOnHover: true,
      sync: true,
      delay: 0,
      hideNonActive: false,
      pager: "#slider .pager ul",
      pagerTemplate: "<li><a href='#'></a></li>"

    });


    $("#slider .cycle").on("cycle-before", function(event, opts) {
      $("#slider .progress .animator").stop(true).animate({"width": 0}, 0);
      var $slider = $("#slider");
      var $progress = $("#slider .progress");
      var $animator = $("#slider .progress .animator");

      $animator.animate({
        width: "100%"
      }, $time, function(){
        $("#slider .cycle").cycle("next"); //everything is a trick :)
      });
    })

    $("#slider .cycle").on("cycle-paused", function(event, opts) {
      var $slider = $("#slider");
      var $progress = $("#slider .progress");
      var $animator = $("#slider .progress .animator");

      $animator.stop(true);
    })

    $("#slider .cycle").on("cycle-resumed", function(event, opts) {
      var $slider = $("#slider");
      var $progress = $("#slider .progress");
      var $animator = $("#slider .progress .animator");

      var propWidth = ($animator.width() / $progress.width()) * 100;

      $animator.animate({
        width: "100%"
      }, $time * ((100 - propWidth) / 100), function(){
        $("#slider .cycle").cycle("next");
      });

    });

    $("#slider .cycle").on("cycle-next", function(event, opts){
      var $slider = $("#slider");
      var $progress = $("#slider .progress");
      var $animator = $("#slider .progress .animator");
      $animator.stop(true).width(0);

      $animator.animate({
        width: "100%"
      }, $time, function(){
        $("#slider .cycle").cycle("next");
      });
    }).on("cycle-prev", function(event, opts){
      var $slider = $("#slider");
      var $progress = $("#slider .progress");
      var $animator = $("#slider .progress .animator");
      $animator.stop(true).width(0);

      $animator.animate({
        width: "100%"
      }, $time, function(){
        $("#slider .cycle").cycle("next");
      });
    })

    $("#slider").mouseenter(function(){
      var $prev = $("#slider nav .prev");
      var $next = $("#slider nav .next");
      var $duration = 500

      $prev.stop().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: 0
      }, $duration)

      $next.stop().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: 0
      }, $duration)

    }).mouseleave(function(){
      var $prev = $("#slider nav .prev");
      var $next = $("#slider nav .next");
      var $duration = 500
      $prev.stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
        left: "-46px"
      }, $duration)
      $next.stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
        right: "-46px"
      }, $duration)
    })

    function position_controls() {
      var $prev = $("#slider nav .prev");
      var $next = $("#slider nav .next");
      var $slider = $("#slider li");

      var $sliderH = $slider.height();
      var $controlH = $prev.height();

      var $center = ($sliderH/2) - ($controlH/2);

      $prev.css("top", $center+"px");
      $next.css("top", $center+"px");

    }

    position_controls();

    $(window).resize(function(){
      position_controls();
    })

  }

}

main_slider();
```

And the html structure is:

```
<section id="slider">
  <nav><a href="#" class="next"></a><a href="#" class="prev"></a></nav>
  <ul class="cycle">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/slide1.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/slide2.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/slide1.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/slide2.jpg" /></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="progress"><div class="animator"></div></div>
  <div class="pager"><ul></ul></div>
</section>
```

The jQuery part is a bit messy now because this is a dev version which I just finished thus it wasnt optimized, there are too many declarations of the variables but it does what it needs to do and there is no problem with timings.